# Can a markup extension be aliased?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, catel

The markup extension that brought me to ask this is Catel's `LanguageBinding`.

I was until now using [Infralution's localization assembly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files), which works more or less the same way.

**Catel**:

```
<TextBlock Text="{LanguageBinding MyText}"/>
```

**Infralution**:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Resx MyText}"/>
```

But as you can see, the markup extension is way shorter to write, thus less prone to typos.

**So I wanted to know if there was any way to be able to use LanguageBinding with another markup extension word**, like:

**Ideal**:

```
<TextBlock Text="{LB MyText}"/>
```

*I'm well aware of readability issues and such, it's an example.*

Comment: How about creating a class with the desired name that inherits from the original markup extension class?

Comment: Why don't you just use Intellisense?

Comment: @Pieter That was my first guess, but I wanted to see if I could get more input. Empereur I'm working on a pretty slow VM, and sometimes Intellisense takes a few seconds to pop, or even doesn't show up, that plus the fact that if I need to prepend a namespace, I've got to use Intellisense twice.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible to do directly in `XAML` but you can derive a class from `LanguageBinding` and use it. Here's an example for shortening the `StaticResource` Markup Extension.

```
class SR : StaticResourceExtension
{
    public SR() {}

    public SR(object resourceKey)
        :base(resourceKey)
    { }
}
```

Now you need can use something like `{local:SR}` as an "alias".

Comment: You can also add an `XmlnsDefinition` attribute to your assembly to make certain namespaces available in the default XML namespace of your XAML files, for example: `[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "MyNamespace")]` - so you don't even need to use a `local:` prefix.

Comment: @Pieter this is exactly what I'm working on right now, but I can't seem to make my XAML files compile with these definitions, even when they are in another referenced assembly.

Comment: [Following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908130/why-isnt-xmlnsdefinition-mapping-my-namespaces-c-sharp-wpf-xaml) on that matter, if someone is interested in answering!

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit MarkupExtension to create your own custom Binding tag

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class LBBinding : MarkupExtension
{
    private Binding _binding = new Binding();

    public Binding Binding
    {
        get { return _binding; }
        set { _binding = value; }
    }

    public PropertyPath Path
    {
        get { return _binding.Path; }
        set { _binding.Path = value; }
    }



<TextBox Text="{customBinding:LBBinding Path=DummyString}"></TextBox>
```

You should also override ProvideValue method from MarkupExtension. This method will be trigger whenever WPF perform the actual binding. Use the IServiceProvider to get back your DependencyObject (Control) and the DependencyProperty (Your binding property). Then you can do all the magic you want with those 2 information.

```
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
       var service = (IProvideValueTarget)provider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
```