# Why isn't XmlnsDefinition mapping my namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Simply put, it's not working one bit.

I know that you can't use these in the same assembly they're defined in, but luckily I work with another assembly all the time on my WPF projects, which serves as a WPF resources repository of sorts.

So in that second project's Assembly.cs, I've added (working with Orchestra and MahApps shell):

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "o")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Catel.MVVM", AssemblyName="Catel.MVVM")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Catel.Windows", AssemblyName = "Catel.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Catel.Windows.Controls", AssemblyName = "Catel.Extensions.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Catel.Windows.Data.Converters", AssemblyName = "Catel.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Catel.Windows.Interactivity", AssemblyName = "Catel.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "MahApps.Metro.Behaviours", AssemblyName = "MahApps.Metro")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "MahApps.Metro.Converters", AssemblyName = "MahApps.Metro")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "MahApps.Metro.Controls", AssemblyName = "MahApps.Metro")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Behaviors", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Converters", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Controls", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Markup", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Views", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orchestra.Windows", AssemblyName = "Orchestra.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps", "Orc.Controls", AssemblyName = "Orc.Controls")]
```

This is to avoid having to define 3 or 4 different namespaces.

But in my current WPF project (which references the second one), when I try to use the `o` namespace, nothing comes out of it:

```
xmlns:o="MySchemas.Orchestra.Mahapps"
```

Intellisense brings absolutely nothing behind a `o:`, and anything I put manually `doesn't exist in MySchemas.Orchestra.MahApps namespace`.

Comment: It looks like Visual Studio is just a bit finicky with regards to this. For me, it recognizes these changes after some time (and a few recompiles).